# Greeter tutorial using Solc, geth and ethereum wallet

Tags: ethereum, solidity, geth

I'm trying to run a contract on a private local network so that I can develop and deploy a contract on the mainnet for some ERC20 token.

Starting with the [greeter tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter), I compiled the default example as follow

```
$ solc -o target_greeter --bin --abi src/the_greeter.sol
```

I also created a testnet as follow:

```
$ geth --identity "SolidityTestNode" --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir testnet/ --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 init testnet/CustomGenesis.json
```

Then I connected to my local network via ethereum wallet by starting it as follow:

```
$ ethereumwallet --network test --rpc testnet/geth.ipc
```

I then assumed that I could deploy a contract as follow:

[image]

But it returns error `Could not compile source code`.

I also tried to enter that code in the geth console, but greeterFactory.new() line never returns the prompt and I don't see any syntax error in the example

[image]

How am I supposed to deploy the Greeter contract on my local testnet ? The tutorial isn't precise enough in that regard.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Uh....you’re putting JavaScript inside the Solidity contract input section. Either use Truffle with the compiled contract or put the Solidity contract code into the UI.

Comment: Oh... makes sense. It wasn't clear to me that the tutorial was about using an ethereum contract from javascript. Thanks for the precision